# Sum third element of each list in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I currently have a list like:

> ((map 9 **150**) (compass 13 **35**) (water 150 **240**) (sandwich 50 **16**) (rope 50 **49**))

I am trying to loop through this list get the values in bold and give a total of these value. I have been looking at car and cdr but I can't seem to get these values. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be the `third` value in the list or the `caddr`. Thus

```
(mapcar #'third products) ; ==>  (150 35 240 16 49)
```

If your list is small you can just use apply:

```
(apply #'+ (mapcar #'third products)) ; ==> 490
```

For a larger list (more than 1000) I recommend using `reduce`

```
(reduce #'+ (mapcar #'third products)) ; ==> 490
```

With `reduce` you can use `:key` to avoid `mapcar`:

```
(reduce #'+ products :key #'third)     ; ==> 490
```

You can also use `loop`:

```
(loop :for element :in products 
      :sum (third element))       ; ==> 490
```